# ios) Objective-c How to add a background image in the grouped table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Hello I have a trouble customizing a background of the grouped table view..
Here's the code I used

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: window.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewBackground.png"]];
[window addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];

yourTableViewController = [[ATableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
yourTableViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[window addSubview:yourTableViewController.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Thank you :)

+added)

I modified the codes but still not working..
These codes are in delegate.m, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: window.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewBackground.png"]];

tableViewController.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
[window addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];

tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[window addSubview:tableViewController.tableView];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and in delegate.h tableviewcontroller is declared.. not sure about this part tho..

```
@interface BetaVersionAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
UIViewController *viewController;
UITableViewController *tableViewController;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewController *tableViewController;
```

Thanx:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the backgroundView property of your table:

```
yourTableViewController = [[ATableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: window.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewBackground.png"]];


yourTableViewController.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
[backgroundView release];
[window addSubview:yourTableViewController.view];
```

Comment: hmm still not working.. Ok, I will edit the question with the modified codes to make sure im doing it ryt

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `UITableView` property `backgroundView` instead of just `view`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

put this code in - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

delegate method

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewBackground.png"]]];
```

Put this on -viewWillAppear method so you can extend your tableView.